# How to detect if an object is overlapping with specific tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Using Tkinter in Python 3.6.0, is there a 'good' way to detect if a specific object, in this case my player sprite, is overlapping any other object with a specific tag?

I would want to do something like:

```
if canvas.find_overlapping( *canvas.coords(player) ) == (player, "item_tag"):
    return True
```

where `item_tag` is the tag applied to 100+ objects on the `canvas`.

I can use `canvas.find_withtag("item_tag")` to return the object ID of all the objects I wish the player to interact with, but I can't get this to work within `find_overlapping`, e.g. take each object ID and let `find_overlapping` detect if it is overlapping.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering both are lists, all you have to do is take each element of one and check if it is in the other:

```
 tagged_objects = canvas.find_withtag("item_tag")
 overlapping_objects = canvas.find_overlapping(*canvas.coords(player))

 for item in overlapping_objects:
     if (item in tagged_objects):
         return True
```

You could do this in reverse and look to see if each element of `tagged_objects` is in `overlapping_objects`, but considering you said there are 100+ tagged objects, that would probably be slower.